# Don't process elements that don't have children

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Generally tag contains XML and \XML in my case some node contains xml/.

Thi is my XML:

```
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <RACON>
        <RACON_CATEGORY>Racon</RACON_CATEGORY>
        <RACON_GROUP>Mo(M)</RACON_GROUP>
        <RACON_PERIOD>30s</RACON_PERIOD>
        <RACON_RANGE>10M</RACON_RANGE>
        <RACON_WAVE_LENGTH>0.03-X,0.10-S</RACON_WAVE_LENGTH>
    </RACON>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <RACON/>  <-- This is the problem -->
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
```

This is my xslt 1.0:

```
<xsl:for-each select="NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT">
    <xsl:for-each select="RACON">
    CIAO
        <xsl:for-each select="RACON_GROUP">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="RACON_PERIOD">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="RACON_RANGE">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is the output:

ciao Mo(M)30s10M 
ciao

I would that if contains RACON/ don't write nothing.
I would that this process run only for structure RACON..... /RACON, not for RACON/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that you don't want to process `RACON` elements that don't have children. In which case, change the `xsl:for-each` to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RACON[*]">
```

Or perhaps you can be more specific, and check it contains at least one of the child elements you wish to output. For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RACON[RACON_GROUP or RACON_PERIOD or RACON_RANGE]">
```

And if you wanted to go further, you could check at least one of the child elements has at least some text in it

```
<xsl:for-each select="RACON[normalize-space(RACON_GROUP) or normalize-space(RACON_PERIOD) or normalize-space(RACON_RANGE)]">
```